# Why Swift doesn't provide signed and unsigned integers in 128 bit forms?

Tags: ios, swift, integer

```
Why there are only 8, 16, 32, and 64-bit forms provided in Swift? Is it because of the range of integers?
```

Sorry for sounding so naive. Please elaborate on this integer storage.

Comment: I am curious; Imagine there is an alternative reality where Swift also implements 128bit forms of integer. Is there an exact post in it asking for 256bit forms of integer? I would say there was no need for 128bit integer so it was not implemented as part of standard Swift library. It is pretty rear you would need it anyway. If you need high precision/value numbers for any reason then you are probably looking for `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: A DoubleWidth type has been proposed in https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md#doublewidtht, but is not yet implemented. Also discussed here: https://forums.swift.org/t/128-bit-operations-in-swift/21639.